# Chrome window.print() window.close() results in 'print preview failed'. Solution?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a print page that opens in a new tab or window. The resulting page opens a print dialog. After the user makes a selection on the print dialog, the page then closes the tab/window.

```
window.print();
window.close();
```

This used to work great in the major browsers, but one of the latest versions of Chrome breaks this (i.e. 14.0.835.202).

I receive the following message from what I guess is the chrome print plugin: "Print preview failed".

Does anyone have a solution to close the Chrome tab/window after printing?

Comment: I would also attempt to use the handler you got from `window.open`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there are any standardised print events. [IE has a couple](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/ie5print.shtml), but I realise that doesn't help you for Chrome.

I think you might be left with only two options. A manual close button or some form of delay using `setTimeout`.

Comment: I previously had in place:

window.print(); 
setTimeout('window.close()', 1000);

This used to work with Chrome, but it stopped working in the latest release.  Chrome reports: "Print is unavailable because the page you were trying to print has been closed."

If anyone disputes that a close button is the only option, please let me know!  Thanks!

Answer (score 31):

I just managed to come up with a solution that fits me. I started out with the reply from Peru  but didn't want to use jQuery in this solution.

```
window.onload = function () {
  window.print();
  setTimeout(function(){window.close();}, 1);
}
```

For some reason Chrome dont start the timeout timer until the print dialog is closed.

Comment: This worked for me on IE, Chrome & Firefox.  I didn't test on any other browsers.

Comment: But when I am pressing ctrl+P before print preview dialog box. Tab is getting closed. Is there any workaround

Answer (score 11):

This question is a top hit on Google so I thought I would add what I found, even though it does not exactly mirror your situation. If you have a link that calls `window.print()` then  its onclick handler *must* return false or you get the error. This is true even if the link is a hash and goes nowhere!

> Print is unavailable because the page you were trying to print has been closed

To fix this make sure you add return false to the link.

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.print(); return false;" >Print</a>
```

Here is the Chromium bug that addresses this. It is marked as fixed for Chrome 17 (not yet released) and I have verified the fix in Chrome 18.

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=92107

Answer (score 6):

Similar issue, I had.

FYI FOR ALL AS OF VER 17+
I was using the jquery plugin, printElement and had found a way to edit it so I could close the window, even in chrome ... then they updated to this new print thing!
I have a solution yet again.

> **Previous**
>
> ```
> Chrome used to open a seperate window containing just the element i wanted 
> printed and its relative css.  That window then spawned the .print command 
> which opened another window containing print preview. By adding a simple 50 
> millisecond timeout i was able to close the previous window without hurting 
> the print preview.
> ```
>
> **The NEW Problem**
>
> ```
> Chrome no longer opens a new window for their print preview. Instead it 
> opens a "dialog with overlay" in the current page to be printed (aka, our 
> new blank page containing just the element for print). Thus, when my timer 
> kicked in, it wouldn't close the page immediately, but as soon as the dialog 
> code closed.  The problem was, it closed so fast, the print command never 
> made it to its service and thus nothing was printed to pdf 
> (what our clinic uses).
> ```
>
> **The NEW Solution**
>
> I knew increasing the timer was no help, since it would just close at the end and could still stop the dialog from printing. Instead, I add a script link to the latest jquery build to the header of the new about page and then added a hover to the body of the page to be printed.  On hover ... CLOSE!!! And guess what ... It works PERFECT!!!
>
> In summery, if you're using a blank page to print in chrome and need to close the page after your element/whatever is printed, simply add a hover event on the body of that page (Or on inner html) that closes the window.  Then, when you have selected a print method and hit print, it will print and close the dialog, leaving you that annoying window. Simply move your mouse a scooch and VIOLA! the annoying pop up window is GONE!

Comment: This is the only solution that I have found that actually works. Kudos to you sir.

Answer (score 3):

All solution above doesn't solved my problem, using this code solved my problem

```
setTimeout(function () {
        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();
    }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

add this script to your popup print window

```
<script src="/assets/print_window_close.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

contents of print_window_close.js is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    setTimeout(function() {
        window.close();
    }, 1);

});
```

basically seTimeout is called only when the document is focused which happens only when the overlay print dialog is closed. hence this works exactly the same way you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

For me i couldn't find a solution so i created one.

What i did is creating an invisible textbox and focus on it by using setInterval every 50ms after the window.print() is called. Also i bound the onfocus event to the textbox and when it get fired i close the window. This is tested on Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer.

```js
window.print();
setInterval(function () {
  document.getElementById("focustext").focus();
}, 50);
document.getElementById("focustext").onfocus = function () { window.close(); }
```

```css
#focustext {
  border: none;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<input id="focustext" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

my current hack. basically, just after window.print(), i bind mousemove, click, and keypress to trigger the action I want (window.close(); or window.location.href=somewhere;). Sure the action doesn't occur as long as the user does **nothing**. But it works pretty well. (well, i can live with until the bug is corrected at least)

```
/* 
// alternative to window.print() for dedicated print windows (had issue with <body onload=window.print()...
// not used anymore.
$('<a id="aprint" href="#" onclick="return window.print()" class="invisible"></a>').appendTo('body');
$('#aprint').trigger('click');
*/
$('body, select, input, textarea, button, submit, form').prop('disabled', true);
window.print();
setTimeout(function() {
    $('body').bind('mousemove click keypress', function () {
        window.location.href=home;                      
    });
}, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this:

```
window.print();
if(/Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent)){
  $(window).focus(function(){
    window.location = '/print-thank-you';
  });
} else {
  window.location = '/print-thank-you';
}
```

EDIT: Printing on Chrome version >= 17 works just like IE/FF, so make sure that you account for that as well

Answer (score 0):

After an afternoon of research and thanks to @SpYk3HH's answer, I've found a solution that works in the versions I am running currently:

IE : 9.0.8...

FireFox : 15.01

Chrome : 23.0.1271.97 m

Safari : 5.1.7

When preparing the html to be displayed on a print specific page, include a check for

```
if (oWindow == null || oWindow.closed || typeof(oWindow) == "undefined")
```

and then notify the user to enable popups temporarily. In order to allow your page to open, display the print dialog and close upon print dialog close add this function to the onload function for the window's body:

```
function PrintPage()
{
    self.print();
    self.onmouseover = (function() { window.close(); }
}
```

The reason this works is because fundamentally we are still dealing with objects and events. The browsers may behave differently in some things, but they all have common ground to look for. A simple onmouseover event will hopefully always happen when a window gains focus, and so this code will hopefully not lose its relevance.

Answer (score 0):

It work fine for me...

```
var newWin = window.open('', '');
//htmlPage is your html content 
setTimeout(newWin.document.write(htmlPage),1000);
// newWin.document.body.innerHTML = htmlPage;
newWin.document.close();
newWin.focus();
setTimeout(newWin.print(), 10000);
newWin.document.close();
newWin.close();
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested today works for IE, FF, Chrome [(including preview fix for chrome)](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/n37QjJcxyLg)

```
    setTimeout(function () { window.print(); }, 500);
    window.onfocus = function () { setTimeout(function () { window.close(); }, 500); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Now we have this event: WindowEventHandlers.onafterprint (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onafterprint).

With this event you can do the following:

```
window.onafterprint = function() { 
    window.close();
};
window.print();
```