# Chrome does not seem to allow for window.print()

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I've been trying to get a simple "print" link on my recent page to work. I set up a simple fiddle to show what I'm trying to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/bladnman/4Ux9U/

For some reason Chrome is complaining about:

```
TypeError: Property 'print' of object [object Window] is not a function
```

You know, this very very simple kind of thing. Been doing it for years:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.print(); return false;">Click me to Print</a>
```

**UPDATE #1:**

Many users have reported that this is working fine for them on Chrome. I still see nothing but the error reported.

I did want to add my environment:

**Version**: 21.0.1180.89

**OS**: OSX Mountain Lion

**UPDATE #2**:
Big thanks to Arjen! It turns out that an extension (Better Popup Blocker) changed the DOM enough as to null out the "print" function on Window.

Thanks again everyone!

Comment: This might help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652981/chrome-window-print-window-close-results-in-print-preview-failed-solution

Comment: Um, what Chrome version are you using? I get the print dialog, both button and link (Chrome 21)

Comment: Clarification please: do you see that problem from that jsfiddle page, or just from a page in your own site?

Comment: I am seeing this in Version 21.0.1180.89. And I am seeing it both on my site and this fiddle.

Comment: I am using the exact same version as you and have no problems at all. Do you have any extensions installed that may be causing troubles?

Comment: OK well it works fine for me in Chrome 21.

Comment: Arjen. I sure hope so. Thanks to everyone who is at least giving me the sanity check that Chrome is not crazy!

Comment: It may be reasonable to report that I'm running on OSX Mountain Lion as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't have any issues with it, but I was able to reproduce the problem you were having on `Windows 7` running `Chrome 21.0.1180.89` by enabling my popup blocker (I use [Better Popup Blocker - Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nmpeeekfhbmikbdhlpjbfmnpgcbeggic)) for jsfiddle.

If you are using a popup blocker, try disabling it for jsfiddle / the site you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

The Adblocker chrome extension in Mojave stops window.print() as well.