# Javascript doesent work in Mobile Browsers

Tags: javascript

Hello i want to redict the user to the index.php after printing thats works well but not in safari tested browsers on PC Chrome Explorer and Firefox but not on mobile apps for me safari have anyone a solution here ? 
best regards

here is my code

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    window.print();
});
window.onafterprint = function() {
    window.location.replace("../index.php");
}
```

Comment: [This sackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26408430/6551181) could work

Comment: ok that post helped me thanks