# How to wait for javascript file to load twitter before printing and close the tab after printing

Tags: javascript

Hey I am using lazy loading for twitter embeds to get loaded on my page. Currently I have given a `setTimeout` of 2000 and after that I use `window.print()` to print the page. But if the net connection is slow then that will not work and if the net speed is good than that's a wastage of time. Moreover after printing I need to close the tab for which I am using `window.close()`

```
block main-script
  // build:js /js/lazy-x.js
  script(src="/js/lazy-x.js")
  // endbuild
  script.
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", myFunction);
    function myFunction() {
      setTimeout(function(){
        var file_name = ("{{article['title']}}".replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z_?: .]/g, ""));
        document.title="Scroll - "+file_name;
        window.print();}, 2000);
        window.onfocus=function(){ window.close();}

    }
```

Its the `jade` file on which I am working. I need to wait for `lazy-x.js` to load every twitter embeds and then print dialog box will appear, after printing I need to close the tab. But tab is not getting closed.

Comment: Do you want to wait for `/js/lazy-s.js` to load and then do sth ?

Comment: After `lazy-s.js` load I need to print and after that close the tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if get your issue right. You can do onLoad on a script:

```
function importScript (sSrc, fOnload) {
    var oScript = document.createElement("script");
    oScript.type = "text\/javascript";
    oScript.onerror = loadError;
    if (fOnload) { oScript.onload = fOnload; }
    document.currentScript.parentNode.insertBefore(oScript, document.currentScript);
    oScript.src = sSrc;
}
```

Example from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement

then your code would be:

```
importScript('/js/lazy-x.js', function() {
    var file_name = ("{{article['title']}}".replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z_?: .]/g, ""));
    document.title="Scroll - "+file_name;
    window.print()
});
```

It's also possible to do it within the jade template

```
script(type="text/javascript" src="path_to_js" onload ="callMyFunction()")
```

Another thing, on window.focus you want to close the window, It might prevent the printing/stopping the JS. Instead of window.focus check the `window.onafterprint` or `window.onbeforeprint` events

Comment: `window.onafterprint` is not supported on chrome

Comment: this question is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652981/chrome-window-print-window-close-results-in-print-preview-failed-solution